# Power BI Install: "Are you sure you want to cancel Microsoft Power BI Desktop installation?"

Tags: powerbi

IE 11, Windows 10.
Running via a Citrix Desktop session.

I download the installer, run it, select English & click Next ... 10 seconds later I get a Dialog Box that says, "Are you sure you want to cancel Microsoft Power BI Desktop installation?".

I would appreciate any help or pointers I can get with this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does your citrix policy allow you to install things for yourself? Email your IT group and ask them to install to your profile or install it yourself on the local machine.

Comment: @DanDonoghue Thanks. The IT guys [of whom I am one ...] told me to try again. I even tried running as Administrator - with the same result. My local machine is an iMac ... but the point is I need to be able to do Power BI development from within the Citrix environment. Thanks, again!

Comment: I'm curious to see if anyone has an answer now, I have it on my local (Windows machine) as there was just major problems for me personally trying to get it on Citrix, then we had the whole version control thing which is a pain when you are trying to implement new reporting options on an old version. I have since given up on Citrix and just VPN into the server with everything on local, of course this doesn't help you being on IOS unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on an RDS server with FSLogix App masking rules in place, I created the rules on a session host on which PowerBI desktop was allready installed. I then copied those rules to the session host on which I wanted to install power bi desktop. The installation failed with the same error.

I removed the app masking rules and then the installation would proceed as normal...

I hope maybe this helps someone in troubleshooting this...